# Spark structured streaming: Current batch is falling behind

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

It seems be very straightforward implementation, but looks like there are some issues.

This job reads offsets (ui event data) from kafka topic, does some aggregation and writes it to Aerospike database.

In case of high traffic I start seeing this issue where the job is running fine but no new data is being inserted. Looking at the logs I see this WARNING messages:

> Current batch is falling behind. The trigger interval is 30000 milliseconds, but spent 43491 milliseconds

Few times job resumes writing data but I can see the counts are low which indicates that there is some data loss.

Here is the code:

```
Dataset<Row> stream = sparkSession.readStream()
          .format("kafka")
          .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBootstrapServersString)
          .option("subscribe", newTopic)
          .option("startingOffsets", "latest")
          .option("enable.auto.commit", false)
          .option("failOnDataLoss", false)
          .load();
StreamingQuery query = stream
        .writeStream()
        .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
        .outputMode(OutputMode.Append())
        .foreach(sink)
        .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerInterval))
        .queryName(queryName)
        .start();
```

Comment: Apache Spark is not a good choice for Stream Processing. I suggest using Apache Flink or Apache Storm. Apache Flink is very easy to use and it's API is like Spark, however, the internal is totally different.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to deal with `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` to adjust total input records per batch. Otherwise lag on your application may bring more records in a batch hence it slows down next batch, in turn bring more lags in following batches.

Please refer below link for more details on Kafka configuration.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.4.0/structured-streaming-kafka-integration.html